# Getting java.io.NotSerializableException with a spring service when stopping tomcat

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

i am using spring 3 with JSF 2
and i replaced JSF managed beans with spring beans, by adding on top of bean:

```
@Component("mybean")
@Scope("session")
```

and in my bean i am autowiring a spring service (which was declared with the annotation @service)

well, everything works fine with the service, but when i tried to stop tomcat 6, i am getting this exception with my spring service

```
java.io.NotSerializableException
```

any ideas why i am getting this exception, and how to solve it.

UPDATE:

after making my service implements serializable, sometimes i am getting following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/spring_faces: no factory registered for this id
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$SerializedBeanFactoryReference.readResolve(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:972)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1061)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1762)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:480)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.readObject(AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:480)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.readObject(AdvisedSupport.java:550)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1496)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:998)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:446)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4631)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally i was able to make it work fine as follows:

**1- The Service:**

```
@Service
@Scope("singleton")
public class PersonService{

}
```

**2- The Spring Managed Bean:**

```
 @Component("person")
   @Scope("session")
   public class PersonBean implements Serializable{

   @Inject
   private PersonService personService;

   }
```

waiting for your feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the error, It looks like tomcat is trying to serialize the entire spring context, I think it might be due to the fact that your are implementing Serializable on Service. I was thinking may be you need to do this, I don't know JSF that well but my understanding of scoped beans makes me think, You might need some thing like this

```
    @Component
    @Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value="session")
    public class MyBean implements Serializable
    {
       //no need to implement serializable on service
       @Autowired(required=true)
       private MyService service;
    }
```

Comment: what does the following means proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, and what's the need for required=true in autowiring

Comment: when i tried that, i am getting exception: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.

Comment: You don't need required is true (just instructing container that this dependency cannot be ignored) it is the default, You need this dependency <groupId>cglib</groupId>   <artifactId>cglib</artifactId><version>2.2.2</version>, Either you can use JDK or CGLIB to create proxy's if you put CGLIB in classpath spring use CGLIB to create the prxoy.

Comment: ok i will try that, but you didn't tell me, what the code means: proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS

Comment: Read this section 3.4.4.5. from the documentation below http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

Comment: well, after adding this dependency, i got two exceptions: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/my_app: no factory registered for this id

Comment: and : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/Type

Comment: oh, fixed it, i was needing the dependency: <dependency>
 <groupId>asm</groupId>
 <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
 <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 4):

You get this exception because the class does not implement `Serializable`. Tomcat serializes currently running `HttpSession` objects including all its attributes to disk whenever it is about to restart/redeploy, so that they are revived after the cycle. Session scoped objects are stored as attributes of the `HttpSession`, hence they need to implement `Serializable` to survive the restart/redeploy as well.

If you would like to make them `Serializable`, then implement it accordingly:

```
public class YourSpringService implements Serializable {}
```

Otherwise, just ignore the exception or turn off serializing sessions to disk in Tomcat's config.

Note that the same story also applies to JSF view/session scoped beans.

Comment: so the issue is that my spring bean (alternative to jsf managed bean) is session scoped and implements Serializable, any spring service used in this bean must implement Serializable too ?

Comment: If you need them to be serializable, then yes. Otherwise mark them transient. I only don't guarantee that Spring will reinject them after reviving, this is beyond my knowledge (I don't do Spring).

Comment: I think the issue is @autowired of service, I think if you make the service a transient then service will not be serialized (since you can't really serialize it any way, It is just a prox)

Comment: what do you mean guys by making service transient ?

Comment: @Jsword: use `transient` keyword. E.g. `private transient Foo foo;`. This skips the property from being serialized.

Comment: so you suggest that i shouldn't make the service implements serializable, and make it transient is better ?

Comment: when i use transient, i get nullPointerException with the service when i stop and start my server.

Comment: to make it work fine i have to make all layers implements serialziable service/dao/entity, and i don't know if that a good behavior or have costs or what ?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `readObject()` + `static ApplicationContext` hack to solve the issue:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class FlashMessages implements Serializable {    

    @Autowired
    transient private SomeBean someBean;

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        ois.defaultReadObject();
        // restore someBean field on deserialization
        SpringUtils.getContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }

}

@Component
public class SpringUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

    static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        SpringUtils.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

}
```