# Bean Validation @NotNull, @NotBlank and @NotEmpty does not work in JSF+Tomcat

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, bean-validation

I am using Hibernate Validation annotations in my JSF managed bean. When I use `@NotNull`, `@NotBlank` or `@NotEmpty` they doesn't seem to be triggered in any way.

```
@NotBlank(message = "{name.required}")
public String name;
```

View:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Name:" /> 
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{person.name}" size="20" />
<h:message for="name" style="color:red" />
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What container are you using?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### Introduction

Since you didn't give any feedback on my comment with the question what container you're using, I peeked around in your question history to learn what containers you're all using. As far I found only [Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502891/getting-java-io-notserializableexception-with-a-spring-service-when-stopping-tomc). So I'll for this answer assume that you're indeed using Tomcat as I initially guessed while posting the comment.

### Make sure you install all JARs

Tomcat does not ship with any JSR303 Bean Validation API/implementation out the box. You need to [download and install](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator/download) it yourself. That you got those annotations to compile means that you've correctly dropped the `hibernate-validator.jar` file (naming may differ per version) in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp. That those annotations in turn does not seem to work in any way can only mean that you didn't read the `readme.txt` and/or forgot to add the JARs from the `/lib/required` folder of the Hibernate Validator library zip/tgz file: `slf4j-api.jar` and `validation-api.jar`. The last one is mandatory in order to get the annotations to actually work. So, to get Hibernate Validator to work in Tomcat, you need the following JARs in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`:

- `validation-api.jar` (contains the abstract API and the annotation scanner)
- `hibernate-validator.jar` (contains the concrete implementation)
- `slf4j-api.jar` (just to get its logger to work as well)

This way [`@NotBlank`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.html) and [`@NotEmpty`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html) must work. The [`@NotNull`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) deserves special attention; empty input fields are namely by default received as empty strings from the client (webbrowser) due to the nature of HTTP request parameters. Empty strings are not the same as `null`, so the [`@NotNull`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) will by default never kick in. JSF is however configureable to interpret them as `null` by just adding the following context parameter to `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This way the [`@NotNull`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) must work as well.

### BV works but only empty fields not

If it *still* doesn't work (i.e. none of the 3 annotations work, but others like [`@Size(min=5)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) for a minimum length of 5 works fine), then chances are big that you've the following context parameter in `web.xml` as well:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You should then remove it (it defaults to `auto`, i.e. only when JSR303 Bean Validation API is found in runtime classpath) or to set it to `true`.

### BV does not work at all

When actually nothing of BV works, also not [`@Size`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html), [`@Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html), etc, then you should verify if you do **not** have the following in your form:

```html
<f:validateBean disabled="true" />
```

You should then remove it (it will just by default kick in) or to set `disabled="false"`.

### Make sure you use most recent Mojarra

When BV *still* doesn't work, then verify if you're not using an old Mojarra version between 2.2.3 and 2.2.6. Those versions had a classloading delegate bug causing Bean Validation on Tomcat and clones to be completely invisible. This is reported as [Mojarra issue 3183](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3183) and fixed in Mojarra 2.2.7.

Comment: hi BalusC, sorry i didn't see your comment on my post but now, thanks a lot for detailed explanation, the problem was that i am having: <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
i didn't saw it, i just used the web.xml from an online sample, and i am new to jsf, thanks a lot.

Comment: @BalusC, I have all required dependencies and on the same (String) field `@NotEmpty` is invoked and works as expected, but `@NotBlank` is ignored. If annotated with `@NotBlank` it does not generate any error even for null and empty strings. Do you know what may cause the problem?

Comment: Like solving a murder case.

Comment: "Since you didn't give any feedback on my comment with the question what container you're using, I peeked around in your question history to learn what containers you're all using. As far I found only Tomcat. So I'll for this answer assume that you're indeed using Tomcat as I initially guessed while posting the comment."

wow...just...wow...

Comment: I do not have access to all of my validation messages. @ NotEmpty in the same superclass is going well, whereas @ NotNull is only showing the default message. @BalusC or anyone got an idea?

Comment: great explanation ,i was using old mojara ...

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and i was able to overcome the problem by including the below three jars in `web-inf` lib. Just add the hibernate validator jar and the required jars as provided in the zip file:

- `hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar`
- `jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar`
- `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar`

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

in web.xml

and add

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.23.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    

    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.13</version>
            </dependency>
    
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.13</version>
            </dependency>
```

in pom.xml

Answer (score -3):

If it still fails to validate even after adding the above indicated jars, then you might have missed adding tag

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in the spring configuration file.

Comment: This only applies if you're using Spring instead of Java EE.