# Controlling the UI Component from POJO annotations

Tags: jsf, user-interface, annotations, components, pojo

I'm working in a Java EE web application using **Hibernate, Spring, JSF and Primefaces.**

My Question is how can I control the **UI components**  (jsf and primefaces components)
using POJO annotations.

**Is there any framework I can add to my project to do this?**

example :

```
class user {
   @NotNull @Max=100
   public String name;
}
```

The UI component associated with the name attribut must validate the string entred (not null and not exceding 100 char.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [bean validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html), also known as [JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303). The reference implementation is the [Hibernate Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/). This is *already* bundled in every Java EE 6 application server complying the web profile, such as Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6/7, etc. This is **not** bundled in barebones JSP/Servlet containers such as Tomcat, Jetty, etc. If you target those containers, you'd need to download the bean validation libraries and drop in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` yourself.

#### See also:

- [Bean Validation @NotNull, @NotBlank and @NotEmpty does not work in JSF+Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545231/notnull-notblank-and-notempty-bean-validation-does-not-work-in-jsf)