# How can I use method-parameter level validation with JSF 2.2?

Tags: jsf, bean-validation, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

I have created a bean validator that I apply to my bean setter method. Instead of getting a JSF validation error, I get an exception raised. Is there a way to make this work, or I should go with a traditional JSF validator?

```
//Bean Method
public void setGuestPrimaryEmail(@ValidEmail String email){
   guest.getEmails().get(0).setValue(email);
}

//Validator interface
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = EmailValidator.class)
public @interface ValidEmail {

    String message() default "{invalid}";

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

}

//Validator impl
public class EmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidEmail, String> {

    private Pattern p;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidEmail constraintAnnotation) {
        p = java.util.regex.Pattern
                .compile("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (DothatUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
            return true;
        }

        boolean invalid = !p.matcher(value).matches();
        if (invalid)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
2013-11-30T20:58:41.747+0000|SEVERE: javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: 
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @144,86 value="....": 
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: 1 constraint violation(s) occurred during method validation.
```

Note: I am using GF4 with JSF 2.2.4. If I place my custom annotation on the field, it works as expected.

Comment: Can [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7548821/1391249) help you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Validation is working properly if I annotate my entities. Will update my question.

Comment: How does your constraint validator (`EmailValidator`) look like?

Comment: I will update the question with the code, but it works perfectly if applied on a field rather than a method param.

Comment: Could you please try to add `ElementType.METHOD`  to the `@Target` annotation on your constraint descriptor?

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work by itself. I was wrongly putting the validator on the `setter` rather than the `getter`. When I moved the annotation to the getter, it worked fine. Would you like to post this as the answer?

Comment: Questions can be answered by experienced people that I'm not :) (I have first time responded to a question). You may post your own solution as an answer, instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ElementType.PARAMETER` is not recognized by the default JSR303 bean validation provider.

From [JSR303 1.0 specification](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/):

> ### [2.1 Constraint annotation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintdefinition)
>
> ...
>
> Constraint annotations can target any of the following `ElementType`s:
>
> - `FIELD` for constrained attributes
> - `METHOD` for constrained getters
> - `TYPE` for constrained beans
> - `ANNOTATION_TYPE` for constraints composing other constraints
>
> While other `ElementType`s are not forbidden, the provider does not have to recognize and process constraints placed on such types. Built-in types do support `PARAMETER` and `CONSTRUCTOR` to allow Bean Validation provider specific extensions. It is considered good practice to follow the same approach for custom annotations.

You really have to put the constraint annotation on the property (identified by `ElementType.FIELD`) or on the getter (identified by `ElementType.METHOD`). Note that a constrained setter is not supported!

Comment: Hi BalusC, can we use parameterized validation? could you provide an example? That will help alot. Thanks in advance.