# spring form validation in object

Tags: spring, validation, view

Say my command looks like this

```
public class MyForm {
    @Max(99)
    private int mode;
    private MyObj myObj;
```

and my MyObj is

```
public class MyObj {
    private String myStr;
    private int myInt;
```

and my controller looks like this

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Anything.htm")
    public String AnythingMethod(@Valid MyForm myForm, .....
```

and my JSP looks like this

```
<form:input path="mode"/>
<form:input path="myObj.myStr"/>
```

how can I inject validation such as @NotNull @MAx @Min for myStr and myInt? how can I specify their error messages in messages.properties? Please help.

Comment: Why can't you just add those annotations to these member variables like you did for `MyForm.mode`?

Comment: @isim, It didn't work even with validation injection in MyObj. If I use `@Valid MyForm` in controller, it only validate MyForm.mode, not MyObj.myInt. If I use `@Valid MyObj` in controller, it only validate MyObj.myInt, not MyForm.mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure if the codes posted in your question are complete, you might be missing a few annotations. Also, since you mentioned in your comment that validations on some of the other fields work, I'm going to assume that you have all the [dependencies sorted out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7548821/1144203).

So try this:

In your `MyForm` class:

```
public class MyForm {
    @Max(99, message="{myform.mode.max}")
    private int mode;

    @Valid // add @valid annotation
    private MyObj myObj;
```

In your `MyObj` class:

```
public class MyObj {
    @NotBlank(message="{myobj.mystr.notnull}")
    private String myStr;

    @Max(/* some value */, message="{myobj.mystr.max}")
    @Min(/* some value */, message="{myobj.mystr.min}")
    private int myInt;
```

In your `MyController` class:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Anything.htm") /* add @ModelAttribute annotation */       
    public String AnythingMethod(@Valid @ModelAttribute('myForm') MyForm myForm, .....)
```

As for specifying the error messages in a `.properties` file, put them all into a `ValidationMessages.properties` file, and add this file to the root of your classpath. (For e.g., `/WEB-INF/classes`, `resources` folder etc.).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your help. Problem resolved. I just don't know how to use @Valid at myObj. However, I am not able to make the message= parm work. I've added `myobj.mystr.max = myInt invalid` in spring's messages.properties (where my other msg are and working). I've also followed hibernate validator's config, adding ValidationMessges.properties to WEB-INFO\, with the same msg string. But both give my `{myobj.mystr.max}` as the message. Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: @senderj All the validation error messages should go into `ValidationMessages.properties`. You can add this file to wherever you are storing your `messages.properties` file. Also, keep in mind, it's `WEB-INF`, not `WEB-INFO`.

Comment: sorry, WEB-INFO was a typo. NetBeans project explorer only exposes WEB-INF, so the ValidationMessages.properties was added to WEB-INF, not WEB-INF/classes. I have to use ant script to copy over. Is there any xml config method to specify the name and location of the file??

Comment: The only way to change the file name and location is to specify the configurations using hibernate-validation ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator and its bundle locator API https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1011623

Comment: it's abit overkill in my case, I'll stay with ant copy file approach for simplicity. Thanks for you help.