# JSF 2.2 Tomcat 8, Bean Validation

Tags: validation, jsf, tomcat, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm new to JSF development and do already have some troubles with the bean validation I can't get to worK:

As a Servlet container, I am using Tomcat 8.0.22 together with JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2).

The problem is that the validation annotations in the code aren't being triggered.

For example, I've got a class customer with an attribute name, which is supposed to be filled by an `<h:inputText>`.
The input is passed problemless to the entity, but the annotated validations aren't triggered.

Neither `@NotNull` nor `@Size` or anything else is triggered, so I guess it's a problem with Tomcat rather than JSF.

I've got the following Jars:

- bval-core-0.5.jar
- bval-jsr303-0.5.jar
- validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar

in the WEB-INF/lib Folder of my WebApp and in the lib folder of Tomcat. Of course they're in the apps classpath as well.

I already tried it with the hibernate validator as well but can't get it running either.

I don't know what I'm not getting here and am thankful for any help!

Thanks in advance!

Benedikt

Here the code:

```
User.java:

package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    @Size(min = 1, message = "Please enter username")
    private String username;
    @NotNull(message = "Please enter password")
    private String password;
    @NotNull(message = "Please enter email")
    private String email;
    private Date birthdate;

...
}
```

Register.java:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Register implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private User user;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        user = new User();
    }

    public void submit() {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Registration succesful for: " 
                + user.getUsername() + ", Username is null: " + (user.getUsername() == null));
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

register.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="Form">
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputLabel for="username">Username</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="username" value="#{register.user.username}">
                <f:ajax event="blur" render="usernameMessage" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message id="usernameMessage" for="username" />
            <h:outputLabel for="password">Password</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{register.user.password}" redisplay="true">
                <f:ajax event="blur" render="passwordMessage" />
            </h:inputSecret>
            <h:message id="passwordMessage" for="password" />
            <h:outputLabel for="email">Email</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="email" value="#{register.user.email}">
                <f:ajax event="blur" render="emailMessage" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message id="emailMessage" for="email" />
            <h:outputLabel for="birthdate">Birthdate (yyyy-MM-dd)</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="birthdate" value="#{register.user.birthdate}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
                <f:ajax event="blur" render="birthdateMessage" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message id="birthdateMessage" for="birthdate" />
            <h:panelGroup />
            <h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{register.submit}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:messages globalOnly="true" layout="table" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>JSFFaceletsTutorial</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please show code as requested in [ask]

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545231/notnull-notblank-and-notempty-bean-validation-does-not-work-in-jsf/

Comment: Well i've read that post already, but somehow i still can't get the validation to work. I've got the necessary jars in the WEB-INF folder and in the Tomcat lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to solve this problem is that I downloaded the Hibernate api for validation from [hibernate-validator](http://freefr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.2.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final-dist.zip).

It comes with the required dependencies in the folder `lib/required`.  I copied the hibernate validator jars and the required jars into the `lib` folder of Apache Tomcat 8.

You should not put those jars in the `WEB-INF/lib` of your application. I tried to put them there to see what would happen, but I had errors while deploying the app.

You might say that dropping libraries in the `lib` folder of Tomcat is not a good practice, but if you deploy your application that uses bean validation in Glassfish you won't have to do all this work because they come built in the JEEServer.  This means that it is ok to have these libraries in your Apache Tomcat server.