# IntelliJ Idea JSF Bean Validation

Tags: hibernate, jsf, intellij-idea, bean-validation

I changed my IDE from Eclipse Java EE Edition to IntelliJ IDEA.
Currently I am developing a JSF project. The project can be deployed without errors, but my Bean Validators defined by annotation like e.g. this:

```
@Size(max = 8, message = "abc")
private String  username;
```

are never invoked. Any suggestions where the problem could be? In Eclipse everything worked correct and the Bean-Validation-Toolbar of IntelliJ also detects the validation constraints correctly.

I am using JSF Mojarra 2.2.8, Hibernate Validator 5.1.3 Final, Eclipse Luna and IntelliJ 14.

Comment: This is not dependent on IDE, but on webapp configuration and server. Tell a bit more about server make/version used and any validation-related settings in web.xml.

Comment: Tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545231/bean-validation-notnull-notblank-and-notempty-does-not-work-in-jsftomcat

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't had any special configuration in web.xml, Server: Apache Tomcat 8.0.22

I downgraded now to JSF Mojarra 2.2.1 and Hibernate Validator 5.0.1 and everything works fine.

Comment: This is not a very good answer. It is in fact a very bad one. There should be **no need** to downgrade both like this. Downgrading one of them a little could be needed, but that could easily be found out. If you actually need to downgrade like this, there is a more fundamental problem (e.g. mismatch of an impl and api, but I'd expect errors then. I **cannot** believe it just does not work...