# Spring Web MVC validation by Hibernate Validator doesn't draw Errors in BindingResult

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I've been using Hibernate Validator in my Spring project. I'm about to validate my `JUser` Object automatically. i.e, I want Spring to validate the Object and set errors in BindigResult. But It doesn't work.

### pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    <validation-api.version>1.1.0.Final</validation-api.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>5.4.0.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
</properties>
....
```

### applicationContext.xml

```
...
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.project.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator">
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
</bean>

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="providerClass" value="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor">
    <property name="validator" ref="validator"/>
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

### JUser.java

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
public class JUser implements Officeable {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
   private String username;

   private String password;

   @NotEmpty
   private String firstName;

   @NotEmpty
   private String lastName;
   private String tel;
}
```

### UserController.java

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
....

@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update2(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @ModelAttribute("user") @Valid JUser user, BindingResult result) {
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("binding result has no errors for user ");
        try {
            JUser updated = userService.update(user);
            model.addAttribute("user", updated);
        } catch (MessageException | DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            result.reject("user", ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException cvex) {
            for (ConstraintViolation cv : cvex.getConstraintViolations()) {
                result.rejectValue(cv.getPropertyPath().toString(),cv.getMessageTemplate() , cv.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return "user/manage";
}
```

As you see in the above controller method I want Spring to validate the `user` Object and set errors in `BindigResult`. But It does not work.
For example when `user` has empty `firstName` I face the output:

```
output:
binding result has no errors for user
```

and I have to catch hibernate thrown exceptions by hand:

```
 ConstraintViolationException: may not be empty ...
```

**more description**. I've used String `@Validated` annotation and It did not work as well. I've read more than ten related stackoverflow questions and they didn't solved my problem.

Comment: Not sure to understand what kind of validation you are trying to do, can you also add the content of the JUser object?

Comment: simple validation by validation-api annotations. question edited.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, can you test if validate is working after adding below code?

```
pom.xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

@Bean // in configuration
    public Validator validator() {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        return validatorFactory.getValidator();
    }


@Autowired //in controller
private Validator validator;

public <T> void validate(T t) {
    Set validate = this.validator.validate(t);
    if(!validate.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

If this works, then can suggest you further to simplify it.

Comment: I want Spring to validate the Object and set errors in BindigResult

Comment: I don't have any problem of Hibernate Validator. I think It is not integrated with Spring. I want Spring to validate the Object and set errors in BindigResult. I want automatic validation by @Valid annotation in controller. I tested your code and it is working. but it is not the solution.

Comment: You can try to add Validator bean in the configuration, and then try @valid

Comment: bro! Are you kidding? I've done it exactly. It is not working.

Comment: <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor">
    <property name="validator" ref="validator"/>
</bean>

Comment: The configuration you mentioned has been brought up in the question content and It does not work. I mean it works but it does not solve my problem.  The if condition is true:
 `if(!validate.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }`
but this `if` is not true:
`if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){}`
I want BindingResult to be filled by Spring. It used to work before updating to Hibernate Validator 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HibernateValidator you must tell to use the HibernateValidator class

By looking the LocalValidatorFactoryBean javadoc

> When talking to an instance of this bean through the Spring or JSR-303 Validator interfaces, you'll be talking to the default Validator of the underlying ValidatorFactory. This is very convenient in that you don't have to perform yet another call on the factory, assuming that you will almost always use the default Validator anyway. This can also be injected directly into any target dependency of type Validator!

So you should use the [setProviderClass](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html#setProviderClass-java.lang.Class-) method in order to specify what class to use

Here it's what I did (i'm using annotation based config but it's the same):

**WebMvcConfig**

```
@Override
public Validator getValidator() {

    LocalValidatorFactoryBean lvfb = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    lvfb.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
    return lvfb;
}
```

**Model**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CANDIDATO")
public class Candidato extends AbstractModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5648780121365553697L;
    .
    .
    .
    private String corsoLaurea;
    .
    .
    .
    @Column(name="CORSO_LAUREA", nullable=true)
    @NotEmpty
    public String getCorsoLaurea() {
        return corsoLaurea;
    }
}
```

**controller method**

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.PUT }, value = { "/salvaModificheCandidato" })
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<String>> modificaCandidato(@RequestBody @Valid ModificaCandidatoDto dto, BindingResult bindResult) throws Exception
{
    BaseResponse<String> result = null;
    HttpStatus status = null;
    try
    {
        this.candidatoSvc.modificaCandidato(dto);
        result = new BaseResponse<String>();
        status = HttpStatus.OK;
        result.setDescrizioneOperazione("Aggiornamento candidato terminato correttamente");
        result.setEsitoOperazione(status.value());
        result.setPayload(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result = new BaseResponse<String>();
        status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        String message = "Errore nella modifica del candicato con ID "+dto.getIdCandidato()+"; "+e.getMessage();
        logger.error(message, e);
        result.setDescrizioneOperazione(message);
        result.setEsitoOperazione(status.value());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<String>>(result, status);
}
```

With this configuration I find in bindinresult errors for both the DTO and the Model

I hope this can be useful

**EDITED PART**

I saw that your issue is to have the bindingresult not empty when you try to persist your object; I changed my code in this way

No change to the model (I used the hibernate validation NotEmpty annotation)

I changed my service method in this way:

```
@Override
@Transactional(transactionManager = "hibTx", rollbackFor = CandidatiDbException.class, readOnly = false)
public void modificaCandidato(ModificaCandidatoDto dto, BindingResult brErrors) throws CandidatiDbException {
    try 
    {
        dao.modificaCandidato(dto, brErrors);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {

        String message = "Errore nella modifica del candidato con ID "+dto.getIdCandidato()+"; "+e.getMessage();
        logger.error(message, e);
        throw new CandidatiDbException(message);
    }

}
```

As you can see I passed the `BindingResult` object to the method

Then I changed my DAO impl in this way:

```
public class CandidatoDaoImpl<T> implements ICandidatoDao<T> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("candValidator")
    Validator validator;
    public void modificaCandidato(ModificaCandidatoDto dto, BindingResult brErrors) {
        Session sessione = getSession();
        sessione.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
        Candidato candidato = sessione.load(Candidato.class, dto.getIdCandidato());
        .
        .
        .
        validator.validate(candidato, brErrors);
        if( !brErrors.hasErrors() )
        {

            sessione.saveOrUpdate(candidato);
        }
    }

}
```

Finally I updated my WebMvcConfig in this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(SharedSpringConfig.class)
@PropertySource( value={"classpath:configuration.properties"}, encoding="UTF-8", ignoreResourceNotFound=false)
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean(name="candValidator")
    public Validator validator()
    {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean lvfb = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        lvfb.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
        return lvfb;
    }
    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator();
    }
}
```

In this way when I have some error on the object I want to persist I have the BindingResult object not empty and no exception is raised

I hope this can be useful

Angelo

Comment: I just did the same. But it doesn't work. I guess it is a version problem. Because it used to work before updating to Hibernate Validator 5.  What version of Hibernate Validator do you use?

Comment: it's strange; i'm using it and it's working.... may you post your updated code/configuration?

Comment: And What Spring version do you use?

Comment: I'm using spring 4.3.6.RELEASE. Now I can't but as soon as I can I'll put my code on github...hoping it cam be usefull

Comment: I use xml configuration. If you see the question text It is same as your annotation configuration:
`<property name="providerClass" value="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator"/>`

Answer (score 1):

As per [spring-mvc-4.3.xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd)

> The bean name of the Validator that is to be used to validate
>   Controller model objects. This attribute is not required, and only
>   needs to be specified if a custom Validator needs to be configured. If
>   not specified, JSR-303 validation will be installed if a JSR-303
>   provider is present on the classpath.

I don't see you wrote any custom validator so you can change

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator">
```

to support the default JSR-303

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Example: [Spring 3 MVC and JSR303 @Valid example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/)

---

Update 1

Could you also try removing [validation-api.version](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/)

> This transitively pulls in the dependency to the Bean Validation API
>   (javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final).

Comment: I have already tested it. It doesn't work as well. It has no effect.

Comment: could you also add `NezBazObjectMapper` and `StringToUser` to gist

Comment: It is simple jackson ObjectMapper. StringToUser simply reads user from db and returns it. I'll update gist as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ExceptionHandler approach. Just add this method in your controller class. I haven't tested this with the `@ModelAttribute` although it should work, I know for sure that it works with `@RequestBody`.

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorDTO processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
    List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

    // your own custom error dto class 
    ErrorDTO errorDto = constructErrors(fieldErrors);

    return errorDto;
}
```

Comment: BindingResult result ? hehe! read the question carefully. My problem is that the BindingResult is empty!

Comment: Did you try it with the ResponseBody annotation?

Comment: But I don't want to return `@ResponseBody`. I want to return to a jsp page and show BindingResult Errors in the form.  
https://gist.github.com/dariushvb2010/f3659fa459646e480ac06edc9d6f8bd3

Comment: You mean I construct a custom exception containing a BindingResult in the controller method. But It does not make sense when the BindingResult is empty.

Comment: Is the ex.getBindingResult empty when the exception handler gets invoked?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545231/bean-validation-notnull-notblank-and-notempty-does-not-work-in-jsftomcat

Comment: Yes! It is empty.