# @NotNull for Hibernate Validator is not working in the entity in data layer?

Tags: hibernate, validation, jsf, hibernate-validator

Im working with Jsf2: XHTML in the presentation layer, CDI Bean in Business logic and Hibernate in the data layer.
I have some inputs in the xhtml file for store an object and submit those data to data base.
I don't want to save an empty object in DB and I validated this by putting `@NotNull` in the attribute in the entity.
The problem here is `@NotNull` is not working and the form still save an empty field in DB.In fact , `@NotEmpty` is working good.

What is the problem please.

Thank you

Comment: Empty input fields which are left blank are received as empty strings and empty strings are not the same as `null`s. It requires some configurations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7548821/1391249

Comment: Thank you  @Tiny. It is done now !